# Efficient search with removal

Tags: algorithms, data-structures

I want to search from a given set of elements. Along with that I also want to remove that searched element. The problem is that the number of these queries is $q=O(n)$, where $n$ is the number of total elements. Which data structure should I use. Also, I want to avoid hashing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any additional information about your setting or requirements, an obvious first choice is some self-balancing binary search tree, such as [a red-black tree.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_tree) It allows you to insert and remove elements in $O(\log n)$ time, where $n$ is the number of elements.

Following a standard engineering approach, try it out first. If it doesn't meet your requirements, analyze your situation more carefully, and try something else.